# My program won't print the sum of the first and last number in the array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

So I'm creating a program in assembly 8086 that allows the user the input an array of character until it inputs a '$' then out of that array filter it out and leave only the numbers and create a new array from those numbers but group them in 3 digits. For example:

The user inputs: 34km12ap111cs345o$
The result array: 341,211,134

And finally I want ind the variable "zbir" to store the sum of the first and last number in the result array in this case: 341+134=475

Here is the code:

```
.model small
.stack 100
.data

    niza db 50 dup (?)
    broj dw 0
    index db ?
    nizaA dw 50 dup(?)
    zbir dw ?
    prv dw ?
    vtor dw ?

.code

  mov ax, data
  mov es, ax
  mov ds, ax

  mov bx, 0

Vnes:
  mov ah, 1
  int 21h

  mov niza[bx], al
  inc bx
  cmp al, 36
  jne Vnes


  mov bx, 0
  mov index, 0

Premestuvanje:
  mov cl, niza[bx]
  cmp cl, 36
  je Exit

  cmp cl, 48
  jl Skok

  cmp cl, 57
  jg Skok

  sub cl, 48
  mov ch, 0
  mov ax, broj
  mov dx, bx
  mov bx, 10
  mul bl
  add ax, cx
  mov broj, ax
  mov bx, dx
  cmp ax, 100
  jl Skok

  mov dx, bx
  mov bl, index
  mov bh, 0
  mov ax, broj
  mov nizaA[bx], ax
  mov broj, 0
  mov bx, dx
  inc index

Skok:
  inc bx
  jmp Premestuvanje  

Exit:
  dec index
  mov bx, 0
  mov ax, nizaA[bx]
  mov prv, ax
  mov bl, index
  mov bh, 0
  mov cx, nizaA[bx]
  mov vtor, cx
  add ax, cx

  mov zbir, ax

  mov ax, 4c00h
  int 21h    

ends
```

However the problem is this. For testing purposes I've put the first number in the array in the variable "prv" and the last number in the variable "vtor". The variable "vtor" seems to hold the proper value but the variable "prv" doesn't. Instead it holds the same value as the value of the nizaA variable and thus calculates the wrong result.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> nizaA dw 50 dup(?)
> ```

This array contains WORDS but you change the index to address the elements as if it contained BYTES.

Simply change `inc index` into `add index, 2` and `dec index` into `sub index, 2`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved me a lot of headaches. You are a boss sir!